# printf is causing a segfault with getlogin()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm new to C, so I apologize if the answer is obvious, I've searched elsewhere.

the libraries I'm including are:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

the code that is failing is:

```
    char *USER = getlogin();
    char CWD[128];

    if (USER == NULL)
        printf("cry\n");

    getcwd(CWD, sizeof(CWD));
    printf("this prints\n");
    printf(USER);
    printf("this does not\n");
    printf("%s@myshell:%s> ", USER, CWD);
```

cry does not print, so that should mean that getlogin is successful.  the segfault is caused on printf(USER);

further testing shows that the folling block prints entirely

```
    printf("this prints\n");
    printf(USER);
    printf("this prints\n");
```

but the folling block will print this prints end then segfault without showing USER

```
    printf("this prints\n");
    printf(USER);
```

EDIT:

Sorry for wasting your time.  I accidentally deleted an fgets that was supposed to follow it and that was causing the segfault.  I've been on this bug for a couple hours now, I love it when the problem is so small.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's in the process of printing `cry` but it doesn't have enough time before it seg faults.  Add a breakpoint (or something) there to verify the `if` block is not being entered.

Comment: try to add:
else printf("%s\n", USER);

Comment: printf(CWD) works if I place it just before printf("%s@myshell:%s> ", USER, CWD);

Comment: ive edited my cvode to express more clearly where it fails

Comment: Post your solution as an answer an accept it to close out this post.

Answer (score 3):

You should check getcwd return value. According to man page of getcwd:

> If the length of the absolute pathname of the current working
>   directory, including the terminating null byte, exceeds size bytes,
>   NULL is returned, and errno is set to ERANGE; an application should
>   check for this error, and allocate a larger buffer if necessary.

Comment: print(CWD) prints fine if I place it before printf("%s@myshell:%s> ", USER, CWD) but nothing after printf("%s@myshell:%s> ", USER, CWD); will print

Comment: The path wasn't that big, but I increased the size of CWD to 1024 to be sure and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

If `USER` is null, `printf` will dereference a null pointer, which is undefined behavior.  The compiler isn't required to do something that makes sense when undefined behavior occurs, so it would be allowed to not print "cry" when USER is null.  You'll want to avoid undefined behavior.

Something else that might be causing your result is the fact that data sent to stdout is usually buffered.  If the program crashes before the data is flushed from the buffer, the data will be lost instead of printed.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how printf works...

1. it has to read in the format string.
2. it has to grab values off of the stack in order to fulfill format specifiers, format them and output them.

examples of things that could cause this...

```
char stringOfTest[5] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
```

or

```
char * stringOfTest = "here are some formats that will be unsatisfied: %d%f%i%s%x";
```

so the first one could crash because the string isn't null terminated, and depending on the state of the application could basically read until it overruns a buffer (a good implementation should guard against this), or just happens to run into a format specifier that causes a crash... This goes for any garbage data also.

and the second one deals with how variadic functions work... all of the variables are pushed onto the stack in some order and the function doesn't have a safe way to know which the last one is... so it will keep grabbing things that are specified until it grabs something out of the stack and (maybe) crashes.

the third way is also in the second example... if you have a %s it will cause a pointer to be dereferenced... so that can also crash.